# How to set PivotTable orientation to value in columns using EPPlus?

Tags: c#, epplus, epplus-4

Does anybody know the EPPlus equivalent of interop code:

```
pivotTable.DataPivotField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
```

Which moves the values from the rows to the columns.

(Manually you'd set this in Excel by dragging the Values from the rows to the columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is `DataOnRows` and it must be set to `false`.

```
pivotTable.DataOnRows = false;
```